# Using two functions (Python)

Tags: python, function

I am re-learning python and I did a functioning exercise.

- The exercise goal was to use 2 Functions to check if a number is a
  "Teen"
- If it is a teen(Age 13 - 19) returns 0 **UNLESS** the age is 15 or 16
- After that, return the SUM of the 3 numbers

I feel like there is a way to simplify the code even more, but I'm not sure how.

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  a_new = fix_teen(a)
  b_new = fix_teen(b)
  c_new = fix_teen(c)

  if a_new == False:
    a_new = 0

  if b_new == False:
    b_new = 0

  if c_new == False:
    c_new = 0

  Sum = a_new +b_new +c_new
  print(Sum)


def fix_teen(n):

  num = int(n)
  
  if num == 15:
    return num
  elif num == 16:
    return num
  elif 13 <= num <= 19:
    return 0
  else:
    return num



no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1)
```

Comment: Well, among other things, `fix_teen` *never* returns `False`, so even if converting to `0` was needed for `False` (it isn't, `False` is numerically `0` already), all of the conversion code is pointless; `False` is never an output.

Comment: @ShadowRanger So, I should change the fix_teen to return "true" or "false"?

Comment: "After that, return the SUM of the 3 numbers" -- your function is *printing* a sum but *returning* nothing (known as `None` in python).

Comment: @peterlloydskubur: Why should it? It returns a "fixed" number, there's no circumstance under which `True`/`False` make any sense. Just remove all the code that converts from `False` to `0` in `no_teen_sum`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
def teen_sum(teen_list):
    sum_teen= 0
    for t in teen_list:
        sum_teen += teen_num(t)
    print(sum_teen)

def teen_num(n):
    if n == 15 or n == 16:
        return n
    elif 13 <= n <= 19:
        return 0
    else:
        return n
teen_sum([2, 13, 1])
```

You can shrink also `teen_num`:

```
def teen_num(n):
    if 13 <= n <= 19 and n not in [15, 16]:
        return 0
    else:
        return n
```

Comment: If we also want to check if the number is 15 and 16? We would do an elif n == 15 or n == 15, return n?

Comment: correct,
this should be first if though as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

if statemenets are redundant as they result in True only when a_new, b_new and c_new respectively are already 0

```
  if a_new == False:
    a_new = 0

  if b_new == False:
    b_new = 0

  if c_new == False:
    c_new = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  a_new = fix_teen(a)
  b_new = fix_teen(b)
  c_new = fix_teen(c)
  sum = 0

  if a_new:
    sum += a_new

  if b_new:
    sum += b_new

  if c_new:
    sum += c_new

  print(sum)


def fix_teen(n):

  num = int(n)
  
  if num == 15:
      return num
  elif num == 16:
      return num
  elif num 13 <= num <= 19:
      return 0
  else:
      return num
  
no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1)
```